# ListView set first visible position

Tags: android, listview, set, position

In ListView I can get index of the first item displayed by using getFirstVisiblePosition() 
How can I set an item at a particular index to display in the first position - I want something like setFirstVisiblePosition( int index )

Comment: Er... simple
ListView list.setSelection(newViewIndex);

Answer (score 26):

You can use `setSelection(index)` so the display will jump to the index you want.

Comment: sorry to bounce this back in to your life but how would you go about doing this when the list is shorter than the screen size? in this case the list does not scroll, however, i would like the first item to be hidden and visible by scrolling down.